# Dealing with nas in R randomForest

Tags: r, na

I am using the randomForest function in R to predict a regression. My data has several missing values. I used the parameter na.action=na.omit in the randomForest call, which seemed to work. But when I predict on the test data and calculate the MSE, I get NA for the MSE. Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?
Sample code -

```
set.seed(1)
train = sample(1: nrow(mydata), nrow(mydata)*0.7)
mydata.test= mydata[-train ,"y"]
rf.mydata =randomForest(y∼.,subset =train, mtry=10, importance =TRUE, na.action=na.omit)
yhat.rf = predict(rf.mydata ,newdata = mydata[-train ,])
mean(( yhat.rf - mydata.test)^2)
```

---

Comment: the set you are predicting might also containse NA.

Comment: Yes that may be the case. How do I handle that?

Comment: @rlerner: either impute the missing values or omit them from prediciton.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar problem in Regularized Random Forest. 
When you say `na.action=na.omit` it will ignore all the data in which there is at least one column with `NA` value. So in your case there is a possibility that in the end all the data is ignored so the model isn't trained at all.

Solution:

1. Check in your data set if there is a column with all NULL values.
2. Remove these columns which have either all NA values or most of the entries are NULL only.

Other solution is you can do.

```
rf.mydata =randomForest(y∼.,subset =train, mtry=10, importance =TRUE, na.action=na.roughfix)
```

What `roughfix` does is it basically exchanges the `NA` values with the mean of the column. Which might be a great solution if you have a very sparse data. But if the data is distributed you need to remove all the columns with `NA` values no other option.

Hope it helps.